# Simulate the Ubuntu window effects in Flash with AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, ubuntu

I need to do the windows moving effect from the following [Ubuntu Window Effects](http://www.72lions.com/2011/01/playing-with-ubuntu-workspaces/) video in Flash. Basically the window is transformed while you drag it. I want to have a movieclip and when I drag it to transform the same way the Ubuntu windows transform. I believe that there is something to do with matrix transformations.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most efficient technique is exposed here : http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/p10triangles/

first triangulating a picture then using drawTriangles method to redraw the distorted plane.

the biggest challenge is to move the anchors around. this second article might also give you a hint: http://www.neuroproductions.be/experiments/nurbs/

you can also look up for "genie effect" in actionscript, there are pretty many sources available. like: http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2010/06/flash_genie_effect_using_drawtriangle.php

happy coding,
cheers :)

@daniel thanks for the trackback :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean the wobbly windows effect ?

You first need to replace the `MovieClip` with a `Bitmap` (create a `Bitmap` + `BitmapData`, then `draw()` the `MovieClip` to the newly created `BitmapData`). Keep in mind you need some extra padding as the effect will overflow the original bounding-box. *

Now, the tricky part which would require a bit of maths (but you can probably find similar algorithms on the web): You need to displace the pixels - one by one - every frame depending on the time,amplitude,angle,...,(and the previous values) of the movement. There are many ways of creating the effect from there, but displacement is probably the first clue for what you are looking for.

But, before going there, I would strongly suggest making a prototype with a single object which would act as *one* of the pixels. e.g. create a basic `Shape` (e.g. a circle) animating in an elastic fashion when you drag it (only the x/y movement, no shape deformation).

**) Alternatively you could work with a separate displacement map BitmapData and apply it to the original MovieClip through a displacement filter, but it tends to be a bit more hazardous in terms of performance.*

Comment: The [DisplacementMapFilter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/) can do most of the fancy maths for you, all you'll need are a set of bump maps to cycle through.

Comment: Sure, but if you want the animation to be as dynamic as the Ubuntu one you really need to ease and apply the displacement with a lot of care don't you think still ? I agree it would be simpler, and it might actually work out really well just applying scaleX/Y depending on direction and amplitude ... defo worth a try ! cheers

Answer (score 0):

you could apply a pixel bender filter while it is being dragged.

have a look at http://en.nicoptere.net/?p=302 there's an example there that shows some of the deformations, you'd still have ways to go to give it that organic look, but it is possible.